# Why is PostgreSQL picking up the wrong column data?

Tags: postgresql

I'm doing this query and it's picking 'ar' 16, when I've specified to only get 'ar' equal to or less than 3?

```
SELECT ticket_id, status,targets, ar, create_date FROM tufin_sc_tickets WHERE create_date >= '2022-01-06' AND create_date <= '2022-14-06' AND targets <= '3' AND ar <= '3' AND (status = '0' OR status = '1' OR status = '2' OR status = '3' OR status = '4');
```

[image]

Any ideas why?

[image]

Comment: For strings, `16` is less than `3`.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? That is a huge mistake to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because ar type is text. you have to cast it first.
change

```
AND ar <= '3'
```

to

```
AND CAST (ar AS INTEGER) <= 3;
```